# Get url parameter in Wordpress get_query_var() does nothing

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress codex says I can access URL parameters using get_query_var() when I register the variable to WP_Query using this code

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = "i_id";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

But that doesn't work the URL

```
https://example.com/contact-form/contact-de/?i_id=12345
```

doesn't give me any id parameter.

```
<?php
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = "i_id";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

$i_id = get_query_var('i_id');
var_dump($i_id);
```

Always prints string(0) ""

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Question: did you add this to functions.php or somewhere else?

Comment: No, nothing added to functions.php, it's in the template for contact form.

Comment: Did my suggested solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this part to your child theme's functions.php:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = "i_id";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

And keep this part in your template:

```
$i_id = get_query_var('i_id');
var_dump($i_id);
```